# Efficient way to find sub-array dividing by n

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have an N-size array A, that contain natural numbers.

I need to find an efficient algorithm that finding a pair of indexes, so that the sum of the sub-array elements A[i..j], is divided by N without a reminder of devision.

Any ideas?

Comment: If A values are random, you can only check every value.

Comment: @Paulpro what difference would sorting make?

Comment: No. The array isn't sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key observation is:

- sum(*A*[*i*..*j*]) = sum(*A*[1..*j*]) − sum(*A*[1..(*i*−1)])
- so *N* divides sum(*A*[*i*..*j*]) if and only if sum(*A*[1..(*i*−1)]) and sum(*A*[1..*j*]) are congruent modulo *N*

  - that is, if sum(*A*[1..(*i*−1)]) and sum(*A*[1..*j*]) have same remainder when you divide both by *N*.

So if you just iterate over the array tallying the "sum so far", and keep track of the remainders you've already seen and the indexes where you saw them, then you can do this in *O*(*N*) time and *O*(*N*) extra space.